# trying to implement selection sort but it wont work

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

i'm currently working on a project where I implement different types of sorting methods to sort an array. I got this implementation from my class but for some reason it is not working. I'm not sure where its going wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    System.out.println(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[min]) {
                int swap = a[i];
                a[i] = a[min];
                a[min] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The Algorithm: Finds the minimum value in the list. Swaps it with the value in the first position. Repeat the steps above for the remainder of the list (starting at the second position and advancing each time). It divides the list into two parts. The sublistof items already sorted. The sublistof items remaining to be sorted.

input

```
int[] a = new int[]{-2, 4, 8, 1, 9, -6};
```

expected output

```
-6, -2, 1, 4, 8, 9
```

Comment: `int min = i;` and then `a[i] = a[min];` - what does it do?

Comment: Please describe the sorting mechanism. Input, current output, and expected output.

Comment: The Algorithm: Finds the minimum value in the list•Swaps it with the value in the first position•Repeat the steps above for the remainder of the list (starting at the second position and advancing each time)•It divides the list into two parts•The sublistof items already sorted.•The sublistof items remaining to be sorted.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala , im not sure what you mean by sorting mechanism but the current input is an array of (-2,4,8,1,9,-6) and the current output is the same order of the input. the expected output is (-6,-2,1,4,8,9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a crucial step to update the minimum index here. Have a look at **if block** in below code.

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[min]) {
                min = j;
                int swap = a[i];
                a[i] = a[min];
                a[min] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `for` loop, `min` and `i` variables.

```
int min = i; //min variable is useless, as min is always equals to i
for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
    if (a[j] < a[min]) {
        int swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[min]; // remember min equals to i, so here you are assigning the same value
        a[min] = swap; // this should be a[j]
    }
}
```

---

Change the `for` loop

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
    if (a[j] < a[i]) {
        int swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `java.util.Arrays` class for this

```
int[] a = new int[]{-2, 4, 8, 1, 9, -6};
Arrays.sort(a);
```

this sorts the array `a` into ascending order (your expected output).

---

Java is pre-built with several tools. Always look for them, writing your own algorithm is fun, but it can be erroneous and painstaking.